Prevent Windows from responding to Volume Up and Down keys when handled by application
I have a MFC C++ Windows app that handles VK_VOLUME_DOWN and VK_VOLUME_UP virtual keys to change volume. However Windows changes master volume as well.
I have tried using accelerators and returning TRUE from ProcessMessageFilter
BOOL CMyApp::ProcessMessageFilter(int code, LPMSG lpMsg)
{
  if (::TranslateAccelerator(m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd, m_haccel, lpMsg))
    return TRUE;
  return CWinApp::ProcessMessageFilter(code, lpMsg);
}

I have tried overriding WM_KEY_DOWN directly in WindowProc
LRESULT CMyDlg::WindowProc(
  UINT message,
  WPARAM wParam,
  LPARAM lParam)
{
  if (message == WM_KEYDOWN)
  {
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case VK_VOLUME_UP:
      OnMediaVolumeUp();
      return 0;
    case VK_VOLUME_DOWN:
      OnMediaVolumeDown();
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return CDialog::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}

Neither worked, Windows changed the master volume before even message got processed by my app.
Has anyone any suggestion how to handle this properly?

I have two suggestions: 1. See PreTranslateMessage applied to keyboard keys handling documentation; 2. See WM_HOTKEY documentation. Be aware in this case. the key will be captured into your application, even if the focus is currently on another application window.
